# Is there any advantage to using body ID instead of body index in Kinect SDK 2.0

Tags: kinect-sdk

The Body interface of the Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0 includes both an ID (64 bit unsigned int) and a user index (8 bit unsigned int).

The user index describes which element in the array of six body indexes are returned in a single frame, and the pixel value in the body index image.

From what I can see the index seems to be as stable as the ID with regards to users entering or leaving the scene (in the sense that they are randomly assigned when an individual is tracked after a period of absence).

Is there any reason I should use the ID to keep track of users instead of the index?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really going to be an 'advantage' to either if you can capture the same results. However, the ID is more intended for the referencing of a person over the user index which is more for tracking who a body part belongs to.
So if your goal is to see if person 1 is left or right of person 2 use ID, if you are trying to figure out if the arm overlapping in front belongs to person 1 or 2 use the user index.